# how to display the input from textboxes in one div ,inside another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I created three divs,first one is parent div and inside it there two divs.I wrote both child divs side by side and gave some input text boxes to take values with a button inside second div floatchild1 and I wanted to display those input values inside third div floatchild2 .I tried to get the values using document.getElementById but it doesnt seem to work how do i get the values and display them.

```js
function onTransfer() {
  var divs = document.getElementById('float-child').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('floatchild2').innerHTML = divs;
  console.log('float-child2');
}
```

```css
.float-container {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.float-child {
  width: 48%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.float-child2 {
  width: 46%;
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-container">

  <div class="float-child">
    <label> First Name:</label><input title="FirstName" id="txtFname" /><br>
    <label> Last Name:</label><input title="lastName" id="txtLname" /><br>
    <label> Age:</label><input title="age" id="txtage"><br>
    <label> Email Address:</label><input title="Email" id="txtemail" /><br>
    <button id="btnTransfer" onclick="onTransfer()">Transfer</button>
  </div>

  <div class="float-child2">

  </div>

</div>
```

where did I make the mistake? is there any way I could use only JavaScript and HTML to achieve this?

Comment: Please learn to look at your browser's console, it'll report errors like this which should tell you what the problem is. For example here, the snippet console clearly shows the error is: `"TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`, because you're using class-names and not `id` attributes.

Comment: I will make sure to look every time from now. Thank you!! your comment helped me out

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: the first is you misspelled the `float-child2` and the second is in your html your'e using classes but in the Javascript code its `getElementById()` instead of classes. I changed everything to ids in the css and html.

```js
function onTransfer() {
  var divs = document.getElementById('float-child').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('float-child2').innerHTML = divs;
  console.log('float-child2');
}
```

```css
.float-container {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


#float-child {
  width: 48%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#float-child2 {
  width: 46%;
  height: 50%;
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-container">

  <div id="float-child">
    <label> First Name:</label><input title="FirstName" id="txtFname" /><br>
    <label> Last Name:</label><input title="lastName" id="txtLname" /><br>
    <label> Age:</label><input title="age" id="txtage"><br>
    <label> Email Address:</label><input title="Email" id="txtemail" /><br>
    <button class="btnTransfer" onclick="onTransfer()">Transfer</button>
  </div>

  <div id="float-child2">

  </div>

</div>
```